# Null Pointer while using radar-netbeans

Tags: java, sonarqube, netbeans-8, sonar-runner, netbeans-plugins

Could anyone please help me with below exception while doing "Get Issues from Sonar Server"

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at qubexplorer.server.SonarQube.getVersion(SonarQube.java:78)
    at qubexplorer.runner.SonarRunnerProccess.configureProperties(SonarRunnerProccess.java:116)
    at qubexplorer.runner.SonarRunnerProccess.createRunnerForProject(SonarRunnerProccess.java:103)
    at qubexplorer.runner.SonarRunnerProccess.executeRunner(SonarRunnerProccess.java:206)
    at qubexplorer.ui.summary.SonarRunnerTask.execute(SonarRunnerTask.java:99)
    at qubexplorer.ui.summary.SonarRunnerTask.execute(SonarRunnerTask.java:34)
    at qubexplorer.ui.task.TaskExecutor$TaskWorker.doInBackground(TaskExecutor.java:62)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[catch] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have installed radar-netbeans-2.6 in Netbeans 8.0.2. I am using sonar qube 6.4. trying to run sonar for maven based spring boot project. Also it is multi-module project and I try it for main project.

Initially it seemed like version related issue. I tried with different sonar qube versions also but getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after a lot research it came up a version issue only.
radar-netbeans 2.6 is compatible with radar qube 5.4 only. I was using higher version on radar qube.

It worked fine with radar qube 5.4. Need to modify wrapper.java.command in sonarqube-5.4\conf\wrapper.conf to the folder where java is installed/bin/java